# NHibernate sets the "ON-DELETE" option to RESTRICT instead of CASCADE

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have a many-to-one relationship between two tables - Patient and Study.
When a patient is deleted I expect all his studies will be deleted as well.
The relevant lines in the *hbm.xml* files are:

```xml
<class name="Study" table="Studies">
        <id name="Uid">
            <generator class="guid"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="Patient" class="Patient" column="PatientId" lazy="false" cascade="all"/>
</class>
```

and:

```xml
<class name="Patient" table="Patients">
    <id name="Uid">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="PatientId"/>
    <property name="Name" />
</class>
```

I'm using *NHibernate 3.3.1* and *MySQL server*.
By setting `cascade=all` I expect to see in *MySQL* workbench that the FK option `On Delete` will be set to `CASCADE`, but instead it is set to `RESTRICT`.
When I manually change it to `CASCADE` (through the workbench) everything works fine.
Is there a way to set it to `CASCADE` automatically? I also tried setting `on-delete=cascade` in the *hbm.xml* file but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, the syntax to auto remove children when parent is removed is...

- `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` (if you want both all and orphan deletes). NHibernate will traverse the children in memory and delete them.

or

- `on-delete="cascade"` **on the key**. Deletes of children will occur on db side.

However, in your case, you try to do this on a `many-to-one` mapping. I don't think this is possible. AFAIK - this is applicable on `one-to-many` mappings only.

To fix this

- You can manually add script to add cascades of deletes on db level (that you've already done)

or

- Change the relation to be bidirectional

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't change the relation because the entities are located in different assemblies. Study knows Patient entity but not vice versa. Is there another way to solve it without adding a manual script?

Comment: About the "different assemblies problem"... Put an abstraction of your Study (eg IStudy) in an assembly that both your types are aware of (or in the same assembly as Patient), and use this in your domain model instead.